# Multiplication weird output

Tags: java

```
long thirtyDayInMillis = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

It should return `2592000000` but it returns `-1702967296`.

But If I split the statement into two statements.

```
long dayInMillis = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
long thirtyDayInMillis = 30 * dayInMillis;
```

It returns correct value.

Why it returns `-1702967296` for `30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`?

Comment: Append a single character `L` after your `30` and see it suddenly work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, numeric literals in Java are `int`s. So the individual parts of your first multiplication are `int`s, not `long`s, and so they're overflowing (the number is getting too big to be stored in an `int`). When you break it up, you convert the value to `long` before it overflows.

You can solve this by adding `L` to the literals to make them longs; just the first is all you really need, since then the result of `30L * 24` will be a `long`, and so on:

```
thirtyDayInMillis = 30L * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Note that I put the `L` on the *first* of the literals. That's because the multiplication takes place from left to right, so we want to make sure from the outset that we're working with `long` values, not `int` values. E.g., it's handled like this:

```
thirtyDayInMillis = (((30L * 24) * 60) * 60) * 1000;
```

First `30L * 24` is done, then the result of that is `* 60`, and so on. So if those earlier ones (which without the `L` are still being done as `int` values) overflow, the result will be wrong.

Your particular expression doesn't overflow until the last multiplication, but let's use values that will overflow earlier:

```
thirtyDayInMillis = 1000 * 24 * 6000 * 7000 * 30;
```

That gives us the (incorrect) result `-864731136` instead of `30240000000000`. Now let's put the `L` in the wrong place:

```
thirtyDayInMillis = 1000 * 24 * 6000 * 7000 * 30L;
// L in wrong place ----------------------------^
```

We get `-39519436800`. Put it in the right place:

```
thirtyDayInMillis = 1000L * 24 * 6000 * 7000 * 30;
```

...and we get `30240000000000`.

Comment: In fact adding an L to the first constant would be enough, the rest will automatically get promoted at multiplication time.

Comment: @TimB: I had added that. I've just updated to make it clearer, and to remove something else I'd added that I believe was incorrect. :-)

Comment: Yes, it was incorrect :) The safest approach if people don't really understand is to put an L on everything. The minimal safe approach is to put an L on the first processed integer (using BODMAS), the minimal will-work-in-this-case approach is to put an L at any point before you overflow.

Comment: @TimB: Thanks. Yeah, I was just proving the order of things to myself over here, I realized I was weak on it... :-) The statement was correct for *this* expression, but **dangerously** incorrect in the general case.

Comment: Exactly. :) It might even be worth pulling this discussion into the answer as I see other answers making the same mistake.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder great answer and got a confusion cleared that `L` needs to be put on first numeric as the expression is evaluated from left to right

Answer (score 2):

You are facing the most common problem of integer over flow,
Use this

```
long thirtyDayInMillis = 1L * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

As per the [documentation of Lexical Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.1) it is mentioned that,

> The type of a literal is determined as follows:
>    - The type of an integer literal (§3.10.1) that ends with L or l is long (§4.2.1).
>    - The type of any other integer literal is int (§4.2.1).

Thus your expression, `30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is evaluated as `int` primitive data type because `l` or `L` is not mentioned in any numeric value. and the result is **`2,592,000,000`**
i.e. in Binary it is **`1001 1010 0111 1110 1100 1000 0000 0000`** and `int` is 32-bit so low 32-bit are taken as mentioned in [**Example 4.2.2-1. Integer Operations**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) which results to **`-1702967296`** as the most significant bit is for denoting sign.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
long thirtyDayInMillis = 30L * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

The default in Java for numbers is `int`. So when you do `30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` you'll get `int` calculations, which overflows.

See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter **L** or **l**;
>   **otherwise it is of type int**. It is recommended that you use the upper
>   case letter L because the lower case letter l is hard to distinguish
>   from the digit 1.

Answer (score 0):

try `long thirtyDayInMillis = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;`

By default its considered as `int` add `L`  at the end to let the compiler know that you are passing `long` values but as Tim B has pointed out *its dangerous because 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 will be processed in integer and only for the last multiplication converted to long*

So do this way

`long thirtyDayInMillis = 30L * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just pointed out the mistake by giving the right code but when i was on the way to add some explanation others have mentioned the same.So stopped in the middle

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As per your suggestion I have added some explanations,waiting for your feedback

Comment: This approach is dangerous because 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 will be processed in integer and only for the last multiplication converted to long. You should put the L on the first processed integer, not the last.

Comment: @TimB yes you are true,changed that.thanks for your suggesstion

Answer (score 0):

it is due to the fact you are multiplying integers which has max value of 2147483647
the right side of your equation stays of type int.
so just try to make one of the multipliers of type long by adding "l" to it and you will get correct result
**e.g.  long thirtyDayInMillis = 30l * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;**